# How do i query a DynamoDB and get all rows where "col3" exists & not 0/null (boto3)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, serverless-framework

This is my DynamoDB table via serverless framework, added a secondary column index for "aaa_id":

```yaml
    Devices:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: Devices
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: serial
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: aaa_id
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: serial
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: aaa_id
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: aaa_id
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
```

I want to query my DynamoDB and get all items of the table where the column "aaa_id" exists or isn't 0 (or null, if it's even possible for a Number type column). Some rows don't include it.
preferable using the `query` method instead of `scan` since i know it's less heavy

I've been on this for hours. please help.

Some of my few fail attempts:

```py
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('Devices')

    try:
        response = table.query(
            IndexName='aaa_id',
            FilterExpression='aaa_id <> :empty',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={':empty': {'N': '0'}}
        )
        
        items = response['Items']
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(items)
        }
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps('Error querying the database')
        }


#################################

import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('Devices')

    try:
        response = table.query(
            IndexName='aaa_id',
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('aaa_id').gt(0) & Attr('aaa_id').not_exists(),
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':empty': {'N': ''}
            }
        )

        data = response['Items']
        while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
            response = table.query(
                IndexName='aaa_id',
                KeyConditionExpression=Key('aaa_id').gt(0) & Attr('aaa_id').not_exists(),
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':empty': {'N': ''}
                },
                ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
            )
            data.extend(response['Items'])

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(data),
            'success': True
        }

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps(str(e)),
            'success': False
        }

#######################

import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('Devices')

    try:
        response = table.query(
            IndexName='aaa_id-index',
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('aaa_id').gt(0)
        )
        
        items = response['Items']
        
        while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
            response = table.query(
                IndexName='aaa_id-index',
                KeyConditionExpression=Key('aaa_id').gt(0),
                ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
            )
            items.extend(response['Items'])
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(items),
            'success': True
        }
    
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)}),
            'success': False
        }



##################################



import boto3
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        
    
    try:
        response = dynamodb.query(
            TableName="Devices",
            IndexName='aaa_id-index',
            KeyConditionExpression='aaa_id <> :empty',
            # ExpressionAttributeValues={':empty': {'S': ''}}
        )
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(response['Items']),
            'status': 'success'
        }
        
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)}),
            'status': 'error'
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over complicating things. Firstly, a number type cannot be null, as DynamoDB is schemaless you simply omit any value.

Secondly, indexes can be sparse. As you're not interested in items which are 0 then simply don't set a value for that, which in turn will mean the item won't exist in the index.

Then you simply Scan the index, as you know that all values that are there are not null and are not 0. In this case Scan is efficient as it's reading exactly what you want.

```
response = table.scan(
            IndexName='aaa_id'
        )
```

Comment: well, i went on using scan. but i think i am still not quite sure how the dynamodb table works. i gave this a quick read this morning: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

i think i'll read again. just tell me, the first example they gave, isn't it the same as mine? because i'm not sure why im wrong. canning is pricy, so isn't that better to query using the newly indexed column? (which btw i still didn't find a solution for that)

Comment: You can only do a Query when you know the value of the partition key. You cannot do functions on a partition key like `Key('aaa_id').gt(0)`, this is why you need to use `Scan`.

Comment: This explains the error outputs (were a bit vague, but now i get it). Tnx Lee!